# Take Multiple values from the php file using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a Jquery AJAX function which sends values to PHP file and the date from the PHP file is appended to the div `content`.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

var valueSelected = $( "#sort_id option:selected" ).val();

var arr = Array();
var arr = <?php echo json_encode($details); ?>;
var details = JSON.stringify(arr);

var wash = <?php echo  json_encode($_GET['wash']); ?>;

var params = Array();
var params = <?php echo json_encode($params); ?>;
var params = JSON.stringify(params);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'sort.php',
        data: {
                data : details, 
                wash : wash, 
                params :params},
                error : function(data){console.warn(xhr.responseText)},
        success: function (data) {
          $('#content').html(data).fadeIn("slow");


            var jsonText = httpObject.responseText;
            var jsonObject= eval('('+jsonText+')');
            var count_array=jsonObject.count_array;
            var count_array=jsonObject.count_sorted_array;

          jQuery("label[for='private_count']").html(count_array);
          jQuery("label[for='sorted_count']").html(count_sorted_array);

        }
      });
```

Now, I need to take some computed value from the PHP script and use it in the PHP file which is calling this AJAX function.
If I give the `datatype:"JSON"` in the above code, it is not displaying the results in the `content` div.

My PHP file contains the following code to be taken into jquery variable along with the content to be displayed in `content` division.

```
$count_array = sizeof($sorted_array);
$data = array(
    'count_array' => $count_array,
    'count_sorted_array' => $count_sorted_array,
);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: from what i see you are new in the field of javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array at PHP level where you put the HTML in a cell within it indexed by `html` and keep the other data:

```
$data = array(
    'html' => '<p>....</p>',
    'count_array' => $count_array,
    'count_sorted_array' => $count_sorted_array,
);
```

Then make the AJAX as datatype:"JSON" and catch the html with `data.html` in order to put it in the content div

Comment: It is not displaying anything, even if i changed my `dataType:'json'`

Comment: log the response to the console and post it here

Comment: [Object, "parsererror", SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at Object.parse (native)
    at m.parseJSO…]0: Object1: "parsererror"2: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at Object.parse (native)
    at m.parseJSON (http://localhost/revamp/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js:4:15948)
    at Pc (http://localhost/revamp/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js:4:18329)

Comment: at x (http://localhost/revamp/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js:4:21743)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (http://localhost/revamp/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js:4:25980)callee: (request, error)length: 3Symbol(Symbol.iterator): values()__proto__: Object